# Cap for globe valve?

Tags: plumbing, valve, plumbing-fixture

I'm "replacing" an old, crusted-up globe valve (not shown below) on one of my hot water line with a ball valve.

[image]

Specifically, I want to simply put new ball valve inline, and leaving old one in place for multiple reasons, mainly being it is right up against an elbow and in a tight space, making removing the body unfun.

Rather than removing the whole valve, I would be okay with removing the stem and capping the cavity.   Question is, is there such thing as a "cap" for a globe valve?  If so, what is that part called? Where can I buy it?

I know how to remove the stem and clean it, so no need to suggest that. I just want to replace stem with some kind of cap, to avoid future problems.

Comment: yes, you should be able to cap it off.

Comment: it's possible that there is such a thing as a cap ... it would be manufacturer specific ... what do you really want to ask?

Comment: @jsotola  Where do I buy a cap for globe valves?  What is that part called, so I can search the interwebs?

Comment: @codechimp i expect that each manufacturer would make the threaded part different from others ... any similarity would probably be a coincidence ... contact the manufacturer ... otherwise, measure the threads on the globe valve and try to find something that would fit

Comment: put up a picture of the actual setup.  probably best to cut cut and sharkbite and call it done in 10m rather than spend hours searching for a cap that may or may not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more likely solution is remove the globe or disc and reassemble with the original bonnet and stem. Use plenty of packing to be sure the stem won't leak. I think you would need to make a solid bonnet. When I put in my sprinkler system , I started with a complex soldered copper tube manifold that contained a brass gate valve. Later when it was working , the Chinese gate valve failed on the third use. I opened the bonnet and removed the failed gate ( large casting defect) and reassembled it. It has not been a problem for years except I use a second valve in the system to shut it down if needed.